# Does Ubuntu encrypt the home folder by default?

Tags: installation, encryption, default

My laptop has been stolen and it contained highly sensitive data. I did have a password that was required to login, but I am unsure if my data is safe. (at this point the data is more valuable than the laptop, so it's a big concern for me)

I remember Ubuntu having an option to encrypt the home folder on installation, but I don't remember if I picked it or not. What is the default (10.04) ? Also was there a way for me to tell during usage or is it completely transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the default settings your home folder is **not** encrypted.

Comment: I see. Is the encryption totally transparent? (ie: if I did encrypt it would I notice something different in day-to-day usage?)

Comment: @NullUserException No I don't think you would.

Comment: It's totally transparent unless you hit a bug, and they're pretty rare.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that it's in use from the output of the command `mount` (without any options) in a terminal; when your home is encrypted there should be a line there that says an "ecryptfs" is mounted on "/home/yourusername".  Similarly, there should be an ecryptfs line with the `df` command.

Maybe not useful anymore now, unless you used those commands...